# React JS - How to pass body request in GET of fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, header, fetch

My Url Params are too big. So I'm trying to get that content with passing it in `request.body`. The **API** works fine with **postman** while testing. But not able to fetch it in **React**

I'm using ExpressJS

**API:** `http://localhost:5000/api/v1`

**React Code:**

```
let result = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/autocomplete",{
            method: 'GET',
            body: {
                "text": "something new"
            } 
});

console.log(await result.json())   // Not get my data here
```

**ERROR:**

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have a body.
```

How i solve this issue ?

Comment: Use method:'POST' instead of GET

Answer (score 1):

It is expected.
From mozilla docs, it mentioned: `The HTTP GET method requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only be used to request data (they shouldn't include data).`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET