# Why does Postman allow Body in GET requests?

Tags: javascript, http, axios, get, postman

I am using `axios` to interact with the backend server, and in the process, I found something interesting. In Postman, it is possible to attach data in the request `Body` and receive responses with the status `200`. However, this seems not to be the case when implementing in the frontend. For example:

```js
axios.get('[target_url]', {
    // would result in "ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" (status `500`)
    'data': {
        'data1': 'value1',
        'data2': 'value2'
        // ...etc.
    }
}).then(response => console.log(response));
```

Many StackOverflow questions mention why `GET` requests do not allow request `Body` **(update: see (1))**. I would include some of them as references:

1. [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
2. [REST API HTTP GET with Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187169/rest-api-http-get-with-body)
3. [axios get request with body and header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445278/axios-get-request-with-body-and-header)
4. [React JS - How to pass body request in GET of fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70242694/react-js-how-to-pass-body-request-in-get-of-fetch)

And it appears the suggested ways to do so, are to either, change it to a `POST` request, or transform data in request `Body` to `params`: [Sending GET request parameters in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068572/sending-get-request-parameters-in-body#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20make%20a%20GET%20request,you%20want%20it%20to%20send%20Body%2C%20clear%20Params.)

**(1):** I might have misstated the meaning, and would like to re-define my statement to the below reference:

> Server semantics for GET, however, are restricted such that a body, if any, has no semantic meaning to the request.

---

Thus, I would genuinely like to take a step further and know the reasons why Postman allows request `body` for `GET` requests.

Thank you for your kind attention and all the help.

Comment: First, because it is possible, depends on your server and its proxy, if exists. Postman is also a debug tool for HTTP-based applications, so I would guess the Postman team would support variety of options to debug any HTTP-based application, because, it is also a debug tool.

Comment: How exactly did you read the answers to [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978061/283366) and come to the conclusion that _"`GET` requests do not allow request `Body`"_

Comment: Asking _"why"_ a particular language, library or tool does something is typically considered off-topic. Even if you could get a definitive, canonical answer from the maintainers, it still boils down to an opinion-based decision.

Comment: @Phil I might have misstated - but I want to refer to the statement that the request `Body` does not have any semantic meaning to `GET` requests.

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your feedback, I did not realise that this question is opinion-based on first thought - as I also thought there are certain right and wrong answers to this question. But I can close/delete it if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616)

4.3 Message Body

> ...A message-body MUST NOT be included in
> a request if the specification of the request method (section 5.1.1)
> does not allow sending an entity-body in requests...

Neither Section 5.1.1 or Section 9.3 prohibits sending entity body for GET method so this was theoretically not a problem.

Also in the latest one, [RFC 9110](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110) says

> ...content received in a GET request has no generally defined semantics...

so this is still not technically prohibited.

But this sentence has ambiguity, so some gateways would implement GET accepting request body while some would not. So for compatibility with most gateways, not sending request body for GET method is recommended.